# Type for merged Parameters of Functions Union

Tags: typescript, types

Let's imagine we have a given functions union type:

```
type UnionFunc = ((a: string, b: number) => string) | ((a: string, b: any, c: boolean) => number)
```

Is there any way to get Parameters of this union to suffice all functions in the union? The main catch is to get these parameters no matter what return types for each function we have.

```
MergedParameters<UnionFunc>; // [a: string, b: number, c: boolean]
```

Also I'd like to have a solution that works for all the following cases:

```
// with rest parameter

MergedParameters<
  | (a: string, b: boolean) => string
  | (...args: any[]) => number
> // [a: string, b: boolean, ...any[]]

// with optional parameters

MergedParameters<
  | (a: string, b?: boolean) => string
  | (a: string, b: boolean) => number
> // [a: string, b: boolean]

MergedParameters<
  | (a: string, b: string) => string
  | (a: string, b: string, c?: string) => number
> // [a: string, b: string, c: string | undefined]

// with less precise parameters

MergedParameters<
  | (a: string, b: string) => string
  | (a: string | number, b: string) => number
> // [a: string, b: string]

// with conflicting parameters

MergedParameters<
  | (a: number, b?: boolean) => string
  | (a: string, b: boolean) => number
> // never

// with multiple functions

MergedParameters<
  | (a: string, b: number) => string
  | (a: string, b: number, c?: string) => number
  | (a: string, b: number, c: string, ...args: any[]) => number
> // [a: string, b: number, c: string, ...any[]]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCATACgQ3hgthYCAzgDwAqUEAHgQHYqFQAUAdK1ooQFxQY0gDaAXQCUUALwA%20HnyliombHgLwSpCQG4AUJtCQoAVRoBLAPY0AYgFcaAY3FNGGboWDwjNRABooAI241LHB8EUUkoFzcPUQAfBydw13cvX25eEG8bbh8TEwAbCF5QqQCgkO1daAVcQgBGezgkVCqlImJNKA6oWMZHZ0SPbz9fHPzC8SkIpOF2zu6WNiQuaQERcagS4PhpqQB6HfCACxNLXJRfaH54yYGU4byCmm9WZjShQW09qAB3I2ADqBMYGAphoGFyUDAWFw%20CI5XAlShOEIACZ6ghkOhETCVFA2h05ld%20skfFAAPxZEYPIoJSKIab4uJ9WmDCn3MZhDZlXb7QhHE5nYIdS5MpIsu6jGjvHTw%20SIwgAZnssHRTSxygYeK6jJpotu1zpa319K1PUJzL1RIyZJFUTWnK2mm5h2Op3OQrNuqG%20oyNsQWusKAgADN3KgpZ8fn8oPlCAwwPAIDYjIRoJDFNjCHC9M1CAAWJUNDHNDO4mYE31io2GonG8s6jxa%202Vmt2wKbbZQT68l0C6BQYX14m%208P7SP-GxmIO5Iw2YENtPQ9VZhGKQgAVjRjUx6fVpYZpv8bYQg2t4qp1dpte13tu2TZNGp9o7Xb5rsF6wgADcEB9R79-jgJzAmA%20RQEG1iziCmbStmcoAGwFiq26Lq0ZbXpatxPheUxoQeg5ik2UA2OSg6PkeDr7r0%20GYeRPrUc87BLK8qwcuRz48q%20vbuhWNGlPAdE3gxfBvJoQA)

**UPD:**

Another curious thing is that TypeScript does it somehow when I declare an array of functions with the same type returns. I wonder if there is a way to reuse it for my specific case:

```
const funcs = [
  (a: string, b: any): any => {},
  (a: string, b: number, c?: boolean): any => {},
]

type FuncType = typeof funcs[number]; // (a: string, b: number, c?: boolean | undefined) => any
```

[Playground with array of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMCMC8MDaAoGMAUAhgFwzQBOAlmAOYA0MARqYWAJ4CUL76AfDAG8AvnVwESZKFVoNmMMAgC2jAKbkGwAPylGIEABsVrLjFZs%20gkdgC62bFDYAHFTABiSYABUnLjA%20cgcPAeEJgKymrWANwwAPSx4qQU1PRMpOGq6jBaOnqGrDAAPjBIACYqcNQqpRwWZthAA)

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMyj6m), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  (For example, even if I define `MergedParameters`, there are syntax errors in your arguments.)   This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: `any` is a particularly contagious pseudo-type that spreads to everything it touches; I don't see how you expect `b: number` and `b: any` to combine to form `b: number`.  Generally speaking, combining `any` and `number` is going to give you `any`.  If you don't want that, I'd suggest `b: unknown` instead of `b: any`.

Comment: @jcalz I wonder how it works on function array declaration. TypeScript somehow merges arguments in a pretty clever way. But only when returns are of the same type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMCMC8MDaAoGMAUAhgFwzQBOAlmAOYA0MARqYWAJ4CUL76AfDAG8AvnVwESZKFVoNmMMAgC2jAKbkGwAPylGIEABsVrLjFZs+gkdgC62bFDYAHFTABiSYABUnLjA+cgcPAeEJgKymrWANwwAPSx4qQU1PRMpOGq6jBaOnqGrDAAPjBIACYqcNQqpRwWZthAA

Comment: Oh, you should definitely mention that in the question itself; if you are trying to leverage existing functionality in a different way, it suggests a different approach than trying to re-create it from scratch.

Comment: @jcalz sure, thanks :)

Comment: Ugh, I don't see a way to leverage that behavior, since it happens when inferring types from values: the type of `funcs` *starts off* as `(a: string, b: number, c?: boolean | undefined) => any`; it is not transformed from `((a: string, b: any) => any) | ((a: string, b: number, c?: boolean | undefined) => any)`… at least not via any type function I can just use. I think trying to re-create this behavior from scratch will lead to a boatload of edge cases.  I'm not sure how far it's worth pursuing.  Why do you want this, exactly? Maybe there's some less extreme version we can focus on?

Comment: @jcalz I'm trying to extend `reselect` library with some specific memorization features. It takes a bunch of functions, calls it with the same parameters, and passes it to a combiner function.  It provides similar typing logic, but with an extremely verbose type definition. So I'm trying to figure out more concise way of doing that.

Comment: Nothing I can come up with would ever be more concise than whatever you're doing now; [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP5Bkw) is my current effort, and it has been hand tuned to the particular examples, and starts falling apart if you look at it funny.  I'm happy to write up an answer, but the conclusion is basically "you can't really do it; try something else".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got properly what you want to do.
Maybe this way below can help you to have some idea.

```
type myFirstType = ((a: string, b: number) => string);
type mySecondType = ((a: string, b: any, c: boolean) => number);
type UnionFunc = myFirstType | mySecondType;


const myFunc: UnionFunc = (a: string, b: any, c:boolean): number => {
  return 1;
}

const myFunc2: UnionFunc = (a: string, b: number): string =>{
  return "1;"
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. What I need is a helper type to get the following tuple from these two function types: `[string, number, boolean]`